# loading XML files by path

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have 814,652 XML files on a single folder, the names of the files are integers from 1 to 814,652.

In my application I load some xml file to a datatable but the loading is not instant, some time a delay up to 3 seconds.

Is it because the folder contains too many files?

If i could divide the files into multiple folders, will that speed things up?

simply i read a single time at a time based on the file name that i get from a selected row in a datagrid

note that i don't need to loop through the file list, all i need is to load a specified file name.

```
 int filename = ;//get the value from the focused row in the datagrid
 mydatatable.ReadXml(path + @"\xmlfiles\" + filename + ".xml");
```

update : dividing the files to sub folders and minimizing the number of files per folder made it even slower.

Comment: how are you deciding which files to upload?

Comment: Are you reading the files by specific names or reading all files in directory and then reading each one ?

Comment: Depending on the size of the document, 3 seconds sounds reasonable to me. How big are these files?

Comment: @DGibbs the average is about 300KB.

Comment: How are you loading the files, sequentially or in parallel? And how are you listing the files (if at all)?

Comment: Some sample code would be helpful

Comment: @Lloyd i don't list the files, i just load a single file by its directory dynamically , just added a sample

Comment: @Jehof i added a sample

Comment: Instead of guessing, I suggest that you [profile this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/308816/87698). This should tell you exactly *where* the time is lost.

Comment: @Shyju i am reading the required files by name, as in the sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have NTFS file system (FAT32 would not hold 800k files in one dir), [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356918/ntfs-directory-has-100k-entries-how-much-performance-boost-if-spread-over-100-s) provides answer to your question, along with some metrics and suggestions.
No, separating into several directories would only hurt performance.

In my opinion, it would be better to either combine all files into one, and map it into memory, or use more convenient storage, specifically designed for quick indexing and access, like database.

Comment: yes sure its NTFS, i thought that dividing files into sub Directories would speed things up but it got worse, i wonder why

Comment: Probably because NTFS loads single directory listing into cache, and then have to reload cache each time directory is changing.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up using sql server dividing the files into tables and using EXI to compress XML.