What's the least resource intense method of deleting the oldest files from a multidimensional directory?
Details for all the inquisitive types, project's open source
I've written a P2P LAN version of Twitter in Node.js. Every user has their own blockchain:

Blocks contain metadata and links to blob UIDs.
Blobs and blocks are dumped into a digestor, which assigns a UID 861844D6704E8573FEC34D967E20BCFE and filepath /86/18/44/D6/70/4E/85/73/FE/C3/4D/96/7E/20/BC/FE.

Each node has a manifest file containing the latest signed metadata for its primary user and all users it's subscribed to, which is served over HTTP to the local network. Network broadcasts allow nodes to find one another.
My question is, when users want to free up space on their devices (there will be gigabytes of post data), what's the best way to delete the oldest data?
I've got two methods I'm considering:

Random sampling where I randomly traverse 100 different paths and delete the oldest file. The shear amount of I/0 for this is concerning to me.

Digester manifest where I keep a file listing all UIDs added, and delete them one by one. The manifest could become corrupted however.


If you have any better ideas, I'd love to hear them.

A couple of options:

You are using the paths based on UIDs. You can add the date components as directories before the UID part. E.g., for today, you can have

/24/5/5/86/18/44/D6/70/4E/85/73/FE/C3/4D/96/7E/20/BC/FE
An application may need to build some index on startup on the first three-four components of the path after the date (i.e., on /86/18/44)

If grouping by date is not feasible, use symbolic or even hard links (depending on the filesystem) to group UIDs by date. E.g., you would have a real directory /86/18/44/D6/70/4E/85/73/FE/C3/4D/96/7E/20/BC/FE, and the directory /24/5/5 would contain a link to this real directory /86/18/44... .

But let me ask, why have that level of deepness? These will be very sparse subdirectories, and the access will be slower, as each directory will have to be opened and closed during enumeration and also to check permissions etc. Possibly, grouping the UID parts like this will make way more sense:
/861844D6/704E8573/FEC34D96/7E20BCFE
If you worry that you'll have plenty of files in the directories, then again, it depends on the filesystem. I once did measurements on NTFS, and it coped with dozens of thousands of files in one directory faster than when those files were grouped like you did. Here's my SO answer on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4357834/47961 (yes, I know that my "benchmarking" sucks, but the point was to figure out what is faster, not get a nice picture).

The reason I used 2 characters is because each directory would have 256 possible subdirectories. I didn't want to go higher than that.
